# Access data frames elements pyspark in jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am new in spark and pyspark.
My DataFrame is composed of several columns and Inside some columns, the is arrays or sub dataframes.

the printSchema of the df is in the [image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6v07.png)

My question is how can I access the elements such as the ["role" the "member"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGYPN.png)
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access member or the other cols ? 
just do that :

```
df.select("group_profile.group.id", 
          "group_profile.group.members",
          "group_profile.intro",
          "group_profile.link",
          "group_profile.role",
         )
```

Comment: And if i want to create a new colum with these values i just need to use withColumn ?

Comment: @A.Dorra yeah you need to  use withColumn.

Comment: @A.Dorra you can add new columns within the select statement